# UTF-8 ucfirst doesnt work

Tags: php

I've looked around a long time now, and all the alternatives and the mb_ functions are not working, any tips for why that might be? If you need any info on my servers part, I can provite that.

Comment: got any code to share?

Comment: Well, nothing that works. I've tried ucfirst, ucwords and so on, found some stackoverflow threads on mb_ucfirst, even user created functions, but nothing seems to work, so I don't have it right now.

Comment: I want to make the string "æsomething" become "Æsomething"

Comment: Siguza, I have tried that

Comment: @Litenhundvilikkeinn [and it works](https://3v4l.org/BeJNb).

Comment: @siguza Does that have any requirements, like something I need to enable?

Comment: @Litenhundvilikkeinn Well yes, [the `mb_*` functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php).

Comment: Thanks, that's what was missing! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works (I know it does, I'm using it in my own projects)

```
function mb_ucfirst($string, $encoding='UTF-8') {
   $firstChar = mb_substr($string, 0, 1, $encoding);
   $then = mb_substr($string, 1, mb_strlen($string, $encoding)-1, $encoding);
   return mb_strtoupper($firstChar, $encoding) . $then;
} // end function mb_ucfirst
```

Use it as `mb_ucfirst($string);`

Complete example:

```
<?php
 $string = mb_ucfirst("ååååeee"); 
 echo $string;

 function mb_ucfirst($string, $encoding='UTF-8') {
  $firstChar = mb_substr($string, 0, 1, $encoding);
  $then = mb_substr($string, 1, mb_strlen($string, $encoding)-1, $encoding);
  return mb_strtoupper($firstChar, $encoding) . $then;
 } // end function mb_ucfirst
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, page just stays white when I use that.

 `$string = mb_ucfirst("ååååeee");
 echo $string;`

Comment: Then you have some other issue in the code. It's that simple. Check the logs.

Comment: Updated with a complete example.

Comment: Thanks, had to download php7.0-mbstring for my server and then it worked :)